# How to show details of Products acording to thier IDs in django

Tags: django

I'm making one basic ecommerce application in Django. I have 'Item' model. On the home page, I'm showing only images and names of the products of the Item model. When the user will select any product, I want to show all the details of that particular product in the `item-detail.html` template.

My view.py

```
def detail(request,I_id):
    try:
        item_detail = Item.objects.get(pk=I_id)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Item not found")

    return render(request, "item-detail.html",{"item_detail":item_detail} )
```

When I'm running the server, CSS is not supporting:

[image: 1]

but the same template is working with a different function (css working with other functions).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to add your `STATICFILES_DIRS` (and put all your static files like css/js etc in this folder) in `settings.py` file. You can also check how to manage static files [here in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/). In your `settings.py` add these lines.

```py
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 'static']
```

And in your `.html` file don't forget to add this in the first line.

```html
{% load static %}
```

And to link your static files use `{% static 'filename.css' %}`

```html
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Comment: I have other templates in the website, that are working fine and have added {% load static %} already.

Comment: Press `F12` and share errors showing in Console. And also make sure to share your `item-detail.html`

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the static files folder is linked correctly. If correctly linked check that your .css file is in the static folder. If present in the static folder, kindly check whether you have loaded the static tag above the link of your css file.